# Do bistellar flips in a simplicial sphere preserve facet connectivity?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-complexes

Define two facets of a simplicial sphere as k-connected if there are at least k disjoint edge-vertex paths between them in their facet-ridge graphs.

Do bistellar flips preserve facet k-connectivity?

I believe the answer is required to be "yes" by topological conditions, and I'd be delighted to know that this is an obvious fact for some reason -- or, better still, that I'm mistaken.